# ASR Setup for VMs without VMware level User Access for VMs migration

Tags: azure, migration, vmware

We are setting up ASR for in an environent. We are having multiple VMs in VMWare environment. VMware environment is managed by Third Party who does not want to give any service account for VMWare as their environment is shared with different customers. So we have access only to the VMs.

Can we treat these VMs as Physical servers and use ASR to replicate these machines to Azure? Is this something which is supported by Microsoft?

I am checking this step by step guide but it does not talk about my scenario: [Replicate VMware virtual machines and physical machines to Azure with Azure Site Recovery using the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure/)

Any pointers for this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to migrate VMs without any VMWare level access. We used the option of "Not virtualized/other" in the "Prepare Infrastructure" wizard of ASR. We treated the VMs as physical servers and did not face any issues during the migration. I am still not sure if this is supported configuration. But I am sure that this works. We have migrated many servers successfully and without any issues using this approach.

You can find more about this at this blog: [ASR Setup for VMs running in VMWare without VMware level User Access](http://harvestingclouds.com/post/asr-setup-for-vms-running-in-vmware-without-vmware-level-user-access/)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot proceed like this. A list of permissions that you need are given here: 
    https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure/#vmware-account-permissions.

You will need to have access to the vCenter server or the ESX/ESXi host with all of those above roles and permissions.

Further, if you're adding the vCenter server or vSphere host with an account that doesn't have administrator privileges on the vCenter or host server, then make sure that the account has these privileges enabled: Datacenter, Datastore, Folder, Host, Network, Resource, Virtual machine, vSphere Distributed Switch. In addition the vCenter server needs the Storage views privilege.

Comment: This is possible. We have just completed migrating 30+ servers using this method. You can treat the VMs as physical servers and migrate. The process remains the same.